# querySelector to find a DOM element which has particular text anywhere inside its tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

```
<div>
    <card class="card-class">
        <header class="header-class">Title 1</header>
    </card>
    <div>Stuff</div>
    <card class="card-class"> <-- This one
        <header class="header-class">Title 2</header>
    </card>
    <div>More stuff?</div>
    <card class="card-class">
        <header class="header-class">Title 3</header>
    </card>
</div>
```

I would like to pull out the DOM element as noted in the example using 2 conditions. The dom element I am interested in has a class `card-class` and somewhere inside this DOM element there is an element with class `header-class` which has a title inside.

I need to get a particular card BY the title text. So in this example I want the card element with 'Title 2'. Is there any way to ahcieve this with just a selector rather than javascript?

Comment: `querySelector` _is_ JavaScript.

Comment: I need to know whether I can achieve what I have described within the context of a single selector rather than get all cards via javascript and fish out the relevant one with the correct title.

Comment: I still don't understand. You're _using_ JavaScript.

Comment: const cardElement = document.querySelector('selector goes here'). What do I need to use as a selector to fish out the element that I described?

Comment: You can't use selectors for all of this You need to look through the text content of all the possible relevant elements to find the one(s) with the matching text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible way I can see this working with one line is if you add a data attribute to the element, and then target that.

```js
const title2 = document.querySelector('.header-class[data-title="Title 2"]');

console.log(title2.textContent);
```

```html
<div>
  <card class="card-class">
    <header class="header-class" data-title="Title 1">Title 1</header>
  </card>
  <div>Stuff</div>
  <card class="card-class">
    <header class="header-class" data-title="Title 2">Title 2</header>
  </card>
  <div>More stuff?</div>
  <card class="card-class">
    <header class="header-class" data-title="Title 3">Title 3</header>
  </card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it´s possible with a one-liner, but here is an alternative:

First you get all the "header-class", that are descendant of "card-class".
Then you loop through them looking for requested title.
And finally you access the parent component, which is the card you are looking for.

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card-class .header-class");

for (let card of cards) {
    if (card.innerHTML === "Title 2") {
        let cardYouAreLookingFor = card.parentElement;
        console.log(cardYouAreLookingFor);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers unfortunately I need a one liner or at least to confirm that one liner isn't possible. What you have described is what I am already doing but it is not ideal. The selector itself is passed to a method inside another framework (playwright)

Comment: If JQuery is an option, you can do a one-liner:   ` let card = $(".card-class .header-class:contains(Title 2)")[0].parentElement;` . If not, I would need to see more of the code to better understand the issue.

Comment: In that case I think your best and maybe only bet is going to be adding data-title to the card element itself